# Paypal Magento2 Order comments

Tags: magento2, payment, paypal, order-comment

[image]I have enabled PayPal on my Magento 2 store and placed an order. Now I am getting too many order comments in order view section. How can I debug this and why there are too many comments showing?

Comment: Show here that you see.

Comment: too many comments i share image